# Docker containers cannot start in Minikube docker environment for a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, minikube

I am trying to build and run a rails app([repo](https://github.com/ryanwi/rails7-on-docker))  in the Minikube docker. But it cannot started. However, I can successfully start it on my local environment.

**The steps I did to cause the issue:**

1. clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/ryanwi/rails7-on-docker.git`
2. go to the app: `cd rails7-on-docker`
3. enable minikube docker env: `eval $(minikube docker-env)`

- if you don't have minikube:
- install via brew: `brew install minikube`
- start minikube: `minikube start`

4. build docker: `docker compose build`
5. start docker: `docker compose up`

The application should be started and rails should be running on 3000. However it throws this error:

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "./entrypoint.sh": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory:
> unknown

**The reason to run it on minikube docker env:**

My original plan was to build the image and deploy to minikube. Minikube can only access the images in its own docker server. I got the same error when I plan to make a deployment with the image. That's why I tried to start the docker first and solve the problem.

**The screenshots are result of commands running in different environment.**

**minikube vs local**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you've included four screen shots of terminal windows in your question, instead of readable and runnable text.  Can you [edit] the question to include the source code and error messages required to demonstrate the problem, as plain text, removing the image attachments?  I can't try to run these PNG files and with the tiny text they're barely readable.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, sorry for the inadequate description. I have updated the question and included the steps to reproduce my issue. I also included the error message. Please check again, thanks.

Comment: Why do you use minikube and docker-compose together? I mean you installed minikube and then doing `docker compose up`. The only thing is coming into my mind is worth trying NodePort access or `minikube tunnel`